# HDF format file to tif format file

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to extract data from .hdf file but I am getting whole data and I only want data of particulate region using a .shp format file. To use .shp i need to first convert .hdf to .tif.

How can I convert .hdf format file in .tif format file using python??

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but this question has been already answered here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code

You can also use gdal comman line utilities as shown here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58688/convert-from-hdf-to-geotiff